# Django - how to save form without validation?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I need to separate form saving feature from form confirming. I want to give user possibility to save form without validating its content firstly, but when form is finished, users should click confirm button which implies data validation and saves it to database.

When I try to save it with `commit=False` parameter it raises error:

```
The Table could not be created because the data didn't validate.
```

UPDATE:
What I did was delete validation in model and create different function with validation which is executed when user finished with form. So I dont validate this form in Django terms.

But if somebody got different solution please answer.

Comment: What do you mean by "save the form" if it does not write to the database. Save it to where?

Comment: So, you would like for users to be able to save the progress they've made filling out a form, does that sound right? So that they can come back later and finish it?

Comment: @sytech Yes, exactly.

Comment: @spectras, save it to database without performin validation in clean() method

Answer (score 0):

in forms.py, you need to specify that all field is not required, pass **required=False** to the Field constructor:

example:

> first_name = forms.CharField(max_length = 150, required=False)

Comment: But this fields are required. Not for temporary save but for final save.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. The solution I ended up with was using two tables:

- one for unconfirmed data (contains data in JSON format and boolean field `is_confirmed`)
- one for confirmed data

If your database supports JSON data type(for example [MySQL 5.7+](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html)), you can stick with only former table.

I think that's better because validation is not only about required fields. Just imagine a user typed invalid date in a `date` field. If you save it without validation, it will be saved to db as `NULL` (or `0000-00-00`). So, the original invalid value will be lost.